# Hide Tooltip for HTML5 validation defined in ASP.NET/MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, html, validation

When the input does not match the pattern specified by the pattern attribute, the browser displays "You must use this format:" in a tooltip on the field.

I cannot hide this tooltip message at all, can I? 'Cause even when I write

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.tbMyNumber, new { @pattern = "[0-9]{6,}", title="" })
```

it stills brings "You must use this format:" in the tooltip for this field.
How can I avoid this?

Comment: If you don't want any message you can just remove the pattern attribute. If you tried hiding it, it would be confusing to users who are wondering why they cannot submit the form. That being said... what exactly do you want to happen when the user tries to submit the form with something that doesn't match your pattern?

Comment: The field is already marked red (light red background, dark red border) with css if input is invalid. The standard validation message is hidden as well. Just the tooltip won't disappear and I don't see why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want without adding javascript. A simple alternative would be to verify with javascript (example below shown using jQuery) instead...

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  if(!/^[0-9]{6,}$/.test($('#mytext').val())) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

This would prevent the form from submitting if the value doesn't match the pattern... without displaying the tooltip... just make sure you have an alternative so the user doesn't wonder why they can't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is not what you expect as answer, but you can probably work the problem around with javascript

**HTML**:
    
    * The string must be at least 6 digits

```
<br/>

<input type="text" onkeyup="isNumber(this)" onblur="lengthValidation(this)">
```

**Javascript**:

```
function isNumber(textbox)
{
  textbox.value = textbox.value.replace(/[\D]+/, ''); 
}

function lengthValidation(textbox)
{
    if (textbox.value.length < 6) {

    document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'block';

  } else {

    document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mvxeous4/1/

Comment: yes, this sample works, but as I want to solve it with HTML5 pattern and validation it's currently not a solution for the problem described.